# What makes concentrated aqueous solutions of aluminium nitrate and aluminium chloride suitable to dissolve noble metals, specifically gold?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, redox

Aluminium nitrate is a strong oxidising agent and aluminium chloride acts as a Lewis acid. Also these solutions are claimed to have the abilities of aqua regia and therefore can dissolve noble metals.

**References**

1. Dissolution of noble metals in highly concentrated acidic salt solutions
   Federica Forte, Sofia Riaño and Koen Binnemans, Chem. Commun., **2020**, 56, 8230-8232, DOI: [10.1039/D0CC02298E](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2020/cc/d0cc02298e#!divAbstract)
2. Dissolving Noble Metals without Aqua Regia,  David Bradley, Chemical Communications/Royal Society of Chemistry, 04 **August 2020** DOI: [10.1002/chemv.202000071](https://www.chemistryviews.org/details/ezine/11256366/Dissolving_Noble_Metals_without_Aqua_Regia.html)

Comment: It is very unusual when a question body  is not really a question.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. Is there any more information you need to come up with the explanation?

Comment: Do you want us to read the articles for you? It seems you have all the information you need?